# What is the best way to handle REST resource proposal generation?

Tags: rest

I have this API : **GET /travels/generate/{city-departure}/{city-arrival}**

It generate a list of possible travels path (with train changes, etc).

Now these are not real resources because they don't have ID (they are only generated for proposal).

What is the best way to select one and save it in a RESTful way ? Should I create a temporary resource for each proposal like **"GET /temporary-travel/{id}"** ?

Comment: Are "these" the travel paths? If yes, please [edit] your answer and include a sample response for a conrete pair of `city-departure` and `city-arrival`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A REST resource does not need to have an ID. It must be identifiable.

One solution would be using a list index (e.g. **GET /travels/generate/{city-departure}/{city-arrival}/{index}** ). This somehow needs you to remember the content and the order of the proposed travel paths.

To overcome the limitation of temporary storing possible travel paths, you may either store them permanently and providing them an static identifier or you may provide a domain specific key that consists of multiple chained static identifiers that provide an identity to your travel path (e.g. chaining all route segment IDs or so).

I somehow prefer the idea of storing all possible travel paths even knowing it is technically somewhat nearly impossible. I like it because the travel paths possibly provided by your system are kind of limited due to the algorithm and the data base you use.

Answer (score 1):

A REST resource does not need to have an ID. It must be identifiable. Your URLs

```
/travels/generate/{city-departure}/{city-arrival}
```

are completely OK to identify a resource.

Comment: While it is true that you do not need an ID, the question how to address e.g. the first of the proposed travel paths is not answered.

Comment: @Alexander That depends on what "it" means in the question. Is "it" a list or an item from such a list? I think "it" is a list.

Comment: Sry for stealing your first sentence.It is kind of perfect.